# Export "Lite" and "Full" versions with different package names for Google Play Console

Tags: unity, google-play, build-process

On the Google Play Console, you can't have two games with the same package name.

Is there a way to have two of the same game with different package names, exported from the same Unity project? For example, a "lite version" with ads and a "full version" without ads.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Package name" in the Unity project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Package Name for an Android project, go to Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings and change the "Package Name". See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Other

If you want to partially automate this, you can use Editor scripts, e.g:

```
[MenuItem("MyGame/Switch to Full version" )]
private static void FullVersion() {
    //I am not 100% certain that "applicationIdentifier" is the correct property, but I think it is.
    PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier = "com.mycompany.mygame";
    PlayerSettings.productName = "My Game";
    PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Android, "FULL_VERSION");
}

[MenuItem("MyGame/Switch to Lite version" )]
private static void LiteVersion() {
    PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier = "com.mycompany.mygamelite";
    PlayerSettings.productName = "My Game Lite";
    PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Android, "LITE_VERSION");
}
```

Depending on your game structure, you may also need to change which scenes are included in your build. I won't get into that here.

The scripting define symbols let you add conditional compilation to your code, e.g.

````
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
#if LITE_VERSION
        LoadAds();
#elif FULL_VERSION
        CheckDailyRewards();
#endif
    }

#if LITE_VERSION
    void LoadAds() {
        //load ads here
    }
#endif

#if FULL_VERSION
    void CheckDailyRewards() {
        //check rewards here
    }
#endif
}
```
````

Comment: so keep the unity project the same but i can change the package name depending on lite and full version and google play wouldn't notice it as a duplicate but it own original package name.

Comment: Yes, if you change the package name (either in the project settings menu, or from an Editor script) and make a build, it will use that package name in the build and that is the package name that Google Play will see.

Comment: awh nice! thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @MM1Content Glad to help. Please remember to mark this as the correct answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Wouldn't Unity consider it as only one project even though I can make two package names? Because on Unity cloud save it shows only one project.

Comment: @MM1Content As far as I know, how it shows on Unity Cloud does not affect Google Play. Google Play looks at the package name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into that.